# How do I set file permissions in Maven POM file

Tags: maven-2, permissions

I need to set "execute" permissions on a file which is a part of the WAR project. Can I do this without resorting to Ant script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found the answer in the "Maven: The Definitive Guide": http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/assemblies-sect-filesets.html

Strange Google wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Actually if you google "maven assembly plugin permission" the first result is the official reference from Maven http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet, next time look at the assembly descriptor reference of the plugin

Comment: I read the guide, but it seems that assembly is intended to create jar/tar/zip files separated from the actual war.
How did you solve the problem?
Can you provide an example? I have a file that I must set with read only permissions (I'm using maven war plugin, with maven 3).

Comment: look under http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-controlling-contents.html#assemblies-sect-files

Comment: I don't think this is a valid answer. The assembly plugin is not used while assembling a WAR file.