# how to set file permissions on files in my deployment?

Tags: maven, maven-3

i have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056403/how-do-i-set-file-permissions-in-maven-pom-file), but the answer doesn't quite explain the technique.

I run my application from the target directory after maven is run on the server.

I have a folder (/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/scripts) which once after maven is run is copied to the target directory (/target/[project]/WEB-INF/scripts).

I need to make sure all of the files within this directory (recursively) receive executable permissions.

How can I achieve this without ant?

Comment: Do you change contents of `scripts` folder or is it just copied?

Comment: The `assembly` plugin can indeed be used to set file and directory permissions.  The location of your scripts makes this interesting.  It appears you are creating a war with scripts inside?  The `/src/main/webapp` dir (aka warSourceDirectory) is not copied into the project dir for packaging until the `war` plugin executes during the `package` phase.  When the `war` plugin completes the archive is already built; too late to introduce `assembly`.  Can you tell us a bit more about your specific use case?

Comment: Are these scripts run from the web application?

Comment: khmarbaise, yes the scripts are executed by the application. Andrew, the scripts folder is just copied, but the 'src' copy created/maintained by subversion and i don't think i can trust permissions to be maintained if a subversion update occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the put the assembly-plugin into the pre-package phase and copy the files to the target/classes/... folder (i'm not sure about the exact name of the folder) and during the copy via the assembly-plugin you can change the permissions. Tha the war plugin will pickup the files and will package them into the war. I'm not sure if this works perfectly. I never tried that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "exec-maven-plugin" with "chmod" executable at "prepare-package" stage in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${org.codehaus.mojo.version}</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
            <id>chmod</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>chmod</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>+x</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/[project]/WEB-INF/scripts/myscript.sh</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It worked for me. I wanted to put the exec permission on a binary copied from source to target/classes.

Comment: can you make it apply recursively ie with **/*.sh ?

Comment: The wildcard character is interpreted as a normal string and you'll end up with a "file not existing" error. A "dirty" solution which works is to add an argument for each file.